# come to work vs come at work

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between:

> **come to work**

> **come at work**

Is it that I can come to my work? (not *come at work*).
And somebody can come at my/their work to do something. Is it a right explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that "come at work" is wrong. "To come" means to move or travel *to* someone or something. The preposition "at" denotes a location or position that something already occupies, so it would make no sense because you can't travel *to* something if you're already there.

Having said that, there is the idiomatic phrasal verb "come at" which means *to attack*, for example "he came at me with a knife", but that doesn't fit your context at all.

Further to this, to "come" is a vulgar slang expression for having an orgasm or ejaculating, so if you said to a native English speaker "I came at work" it would result in some laughter.

Comment: There's also the idea of problem solving - something like "come at work from a different angle" - to mean trying a different approach to solving a problem